# 1970's? (or 1980s?) graphic novel about a swords-and-sandals protagonist that founds a space-faring kingdom that lands a ship on Earth

Tags: story-identification, comics, space, graphic-novel

When I was a kid, I remembered finding a very old comic book (I think it might have been from the 70s or 80s) that had a unique plot.

The comic opens up with a spaceship with a space crew that was all dead landing on Earth, and nobody knew where they came from.

The ship also contains an archive that was written in an alien language that nobody can read.

While it was a sensation at first, everyone forgot about it, and after a while people stopped trying to read the alien language.

Except for one scientist who kept trying to read it, until he finally deciphered the language.

The actual story then begins, and it talks about this alien world that kind of resembles Conan the barbarian, but it isn’t that. It shows this hero guy with a sword that has adventures and then he finally builds up his kingdom and country by fighting strange looking aliens, etc.

It was implied that this guy was the founder of the civilization that eventually launched the spaceship into space that then landed on Earth.

Never finished the book (it was a HUGE graphic novel) but that story always haunted me.
Does this ring a bell for anyone? I am trying to figure out the title and maybe if I can read it again (the last time I saw the book was when I was a kid in the 90s).

One of his adventures for example is when the protagonist became a king he found a farmer that developed flight technology (think Wright Brothers from the 1900s) and used it to turn a war in his favor by replicating it or something like that.

Comment: Just to be clear, on the spaceship, there was an archive in an alien language, and the "sword and sorcery" bit was what the archive discussed?

Comment: If a correct answer is posted, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 7):

I've not read it, but this sounds suspiciously similar to [The Trigan Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Trigan_Empire)

The first story is [Victory of the Trigans](https://vorg.org.nz/victory-for-the-trigans/), which starts with a spacecraft crashing in Florida, with all the crew being dead on arrival; and a scientist spending years deciphering the language.

It's definitely a large book - the story is currently being reprinted, and is on Volume 6; and it originally dates from 1965.

The story that the scientist discovers is the history of the Trigan Empire, starting off with a nomadic people, which fits very nicely with your sword-and-sandal memories.

Comment: I can say definitely that this is the right answer. I have the first 4 volumes of the reprint collection, and everything fits down to the Wright Brothers plane (seen here: https://bookpalace.com/acatalog/info-TRIGAN03.html)